# How to convert a string with equal "=" sign to json in JavaScript

Tags: lambda, apache-kafka, jsonparser

The Following String is returned from Kafka to Lambda Connector.

```
'{device_id=D_2021_A07, key=tele_metrics, sensor_1=62, sensor_2=23}'
```

I want to convert this to a valid JSON like this

```
{
    "device_id": "D_2021_A07",   //String
    "key": "tele_metrics",       //String
    "sensor_1": 62,              //Integer
    "sensor_2": 23               //Integer
}
```

How can I do that in Javascript.

Comment: I’d investigate how to change the format of the data delivered by Kafka. Because the string you get is rubbish. It’s not parseable.

Comment: @gnasher729 as long as the format is documented, it's parseable. It's just not JSON. It may be a proprietary format, but that doesn't prevent it from being parsed, even if it has to be done manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can strip the first and last character, split at the commas, split at each `=`, convert the values to numbers if possible, and then combine the pairs to an object:

```js
const dataA = '{device_id=D_2021_A07, key=tele_metrics, sensor_1=62, sensor_2=23}';
const dataB = Object.fromEntries(
  dataA
    .substring(1, dataA.length - 1)
    .split(', ')
    .map(pair => pair.split('='))
    .map(([key, value]) => [key, isNaN(value) ? value : +value])
);
console.log(dataB);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dataB));
```

Comment: This works Good, As expected.

Comment: This solution will not solve arrays

Comment: @Charlie-Greenman Arrays were not mentioned in the question. Search or ask a new question if you have different requirements.